# How can I transform a webapp/ website into a windows10 app?

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, modern-ui

I would like to have some websites easily available on my desktop.

The first thing that comes to my mind is a simple shortcut to the website, yet this is not as satisfactory as I would like.

The best example of my need is to have a cvasi-native youtube app for w10, given that the existing metro apps don't seem to do the job quite right.

In other words, I would like to have all the functionality of the site, not within a browser's window, but in some kind of a w10 simple window. I will use that specific window only for that app without navigating to another website.

For a better illustration, take the mobile apps use-case. They provide all the functions which the browser based version do but within a natively encapsulated container.

That's about it. Any ideas?

Comment: Edge or Chrome can "install" websites as applications, does that suit what you need? https://allthings.how/how-to-install-any-website-as-app-using-edge-chrome-browser/

Comment: Yes it does, thank you!